# write into a text file from a list<T> c#

Tags: c#, list

I am working with c# and I have a list of type list where Family is a class with this structure:

```
public class Family
    {
        public Father father;
        public Mother mother;
        public int IdFamily { get; set; }
    }
```

Father and Mother are also classes with their own attributes.

My list has got data about the families. I want to store all that data from the list into a txt files.

How I can do this using System.IO  and StreamWriter?

Comment: And in what structure? XML? JSON? something else?

Comment: Does the format matter? Specifically, why not just serialize to a JSON string, then write that to a file?

Comment: Format doesn't matter

Comment: Go for JSON, Newtonsoft JSON is easy to use and performs well

Comment: Can you add a sample of the list from where you want to extract the information? To see what kind of information is stored there

Comment: yes for example my liste countains information about each family. information are of this type
fatherFullName
fatherAge
MotherFullName
motherAge
FamilyID
@IgnacioAlorre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go for Json then it's quite straight forward with [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(family, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(path, json);
```